Permission denied when saving Keras Model
I am getting  a permission denied error when trying to save the model through call-backs. The model appears to initially save as the file is there, but then there is the below error at some point through the training process.
I have full access to the file path and can create/delete files through the terminal that I am running the script, but cant save for some reason.
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\7311392\\code\\solarSearcher\\training.py", line 134, in \<module\>
model.fit(
File "C:\\Users\\7311392\\PycharmProjects\\CustomerScreeningTechniques\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\\Users\\7311392\\PycharmProjects\\CustomerScreeningTechniques\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\saving\\saving_lib.py", line 141, in save_model
with open(filepath, "wb") as f:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\7311392\\Downloads\\roof_identification.keras'

Code:
#Training
model.compile(
   optimizer=optimizers.Adam(1e-4), 
   loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
)

callbacks = [
    callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(r'C:\Users\7311392\Downloads\roof_identification.keras', save_best_only=True),
]

epochs =50
model.fit(
   train_dataset,
   epochs=epochs,
   validation_data=val_dataset,
   callbacks=callbacks,
   verbose=2
)
model = models.load_model('roof_identification.keras')
val_preds = model.predict(val_dataset)

def display_mask(i):
   """Quick utility to display a model's prediction."""
   mask = np.argmax(val_preds[i], axis=-1)
   mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
   img = ImageOps.autocontrast(utils.array_to_img(mask))
   img.show()

Image.open(val_input_img_paths[10]).show()
img = Image.open(val_mask_img_paths[10]).show()
display_mask(10)

